# Search files in folder Powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to search files in folder, and open it by clicking ok button on the Out-Gridview

```
gci | Out-GridView -PassThru | Select Name
```

I try using StartProcess but i need to provide name of file. I dont know how to get name of the file from out-gridview and paste it to the Start-Process -FilePath

Comment: If the extension is associated with an application try `& (Get-ChildItem -File | Out-GridView -PassThru | Select-Object FullName).FullName`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Invoke-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Invoke-Item?view=powershell-5.0). It opens a file with its default handler.

```
Get-ChildItem -File | Out-GridView -PassThru |
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName | Invoke-Item
```